# Vue.js router does not work with dynamic params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

VueJs Router does not work when accessing a similar path with different parameters.

I am trying to access a dynamic address where only changes the ID of the page that goes as a parameter.

The address in the browser changes, but the page content continues from the current state.

Could anyone help?

```
this.$router.push({ path: `/vendas/detalhes/${data.id}` })
```

Comment: Can you should your defined route?

Comment: { path: '/vendas/detalhes/:id', component: () => import('/pages/detalhes.vue') },

Comment: Can't you define a named route? And try passing in the `id` as a param?

Comment: It also does not work. Same result.

Comment: Here is the relevant part in the vue-router documentation ~ https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Comment: How can I do it? Could you exemplify?

Comment: Define route as: { name:'detalhes', path: '/vendas/detalhes/:id', component: () => import('/pages/detalhes.vue') } and in component use the following: this.$router.push({ name: 'detalhes', params: { id: data.id } })

Comment: I've done this, but it doesn't work